# Numpy: Efficient way to sort array and find corresponding indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array and want to get both the sorted array and the correspoding indices from an original one. E.g.

```py
arr = [2,1,3]
sorted_arr = [1,2,3]
sorted_indices = [1,0,2]
```

I know I can use `np.sort(arr)` and `np.argsort(arr)` to find them separately. But is there more efficient way that doesn't require sorting one array two times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to sort twice. If you need the indices that sort the array, you'll need [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), but in order to sort the values in `arr` you only need to index with the result from `np.argsort`:

```
s = np.argsort(arr)
# array([1, 0, 2])
arr[s]
# array([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use argsort to get the sorted array.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([2,1,3])
sorted_indices = np.argsort(arr)
sorted_arr = arr[sorted_indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the list elements and their indices in the same list using `enumerate`:

```py
arr = [(x, i) for i,x in enumerate(arr)]

# Now you can use np.sort(arr) and unpack as necessary
np.sort(arr)
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 3]])

for x, idx in np.sort(arr):
    print(x, idx)
```